# android Loosing context on web view when creating new task

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two applications. The first one A has a web view with a link to another application and a timestamp. 
In this web view, I have a link that opens another application B. In B, I have a button. The click on the button should take me back to app A, 
without reloading it, and executing a javascript code that should populate some other fields in the web view.
As a result, App A should be brought back, timestamp should not be changed and the javascript called and fields properly populated.

The problem is if I do this scenario and I start app B from A using only StartActivity(), it doesn't work. I'm able to do A-B and B-A but my javascript is not called 
because A is not called with the proper intent. In other words, when calling A from B, I should find in the intent object the action and the data that took me to A but instead the action in the intent is NULL

If in the other hand, I add a flag when starting Activity on B : FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK. it works one time. A->B->A but after that I'm not able to call B again. 
Another test I made: If I start calling B from the home screen and than A and than B. It works. So I guess it has to do with the fact that B is different if called using intent from A or from home screen.

Anyway, I couldn't make it open the app, call the js and keep the context all in the same time.

I only tried on emulator.

Here is Manifest for App A

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.cgi.csb.launcher"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="12"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name=".Activity1" launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:host="localhost" android:scheme="myactivity"></data>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Here is the manifest for App B

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.CallerApp"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="12"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".Activity2" launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data
                        android:host="dummy"
                        android:scheme="testintentapp"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

To call B from A :

```
@Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
                startActivity(intent);

                return true;
            }
```

To call A from B :

```
case R.id.button:
                   Intent intent = new Intent();
                   intent.setData(Uri.parse("myactivity://localhost"));
                   intent.putExtra("firstKeyName","FirstKeyValue");
                   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
                   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                   startActivity(intent);
                   finish();
                   break;
```

The code I use to differentiate when A is called from home or from App B to call the javascript

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    if ("myactivity://localhost".equals(intent.getDataString())) {
        Log.d(TAG, "*** Call JS with action : " + intent.getAction());
        _jsHandler.javaFnCall("Hardcoded params");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "***Just call the app with action :" + intent.getAction());
    }
```

Thanks a lot !